# Add command to every context menu associated with text in word 2007 `

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

it is pretty simple to add a command to the context menu in Word 2007 like shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723154%28VS.90%29) but is there a way to add the command to all context menus associated with any kind of text. I've tried iterating over some of the command bars and adding the new control - but this is slowing the application start down. Is there any other way - something like "root" command bar for any kind of text?